# How can I to see the code coverage per each test?

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco, junit5, jacoco-maven-plugin

Is it possible to achieve a code coverage per *each single test method* with JaCoCo and Maven and to see it SonarQube?

I wish to see additionally by which unit test(s) a line or condition has been covered. Instead it shows me only the coverage of all tests combined, in the JaCoCo report and in SonarQube.

The generated jacoco.xml file does not contain any information on tests but only the source classes and methods. I think many years ago at some other place I managed to achieve a per test coverage, but I do not remember the solution.

There is a [old blog](https://deors.wordpress.com/2014/07/04/individual-test-coverage-sonarqube-jacoco/) which says to add a argline to Surefire configuration in Maven POM file: -XX:-UseSplitVerifier. But that does not work with newer Java versions (11 and above) as it turned out.

Does someone know if that is possible with the latest versions of JaCoCo, Maven, JUnit 5, SonarQube and Java?